# Are there black outlines on this page with IE?

Tags: html, css

My customer is telling me there are black outlines around the elliptical links on this page

http://animactions.ca/volet_entreprise.php

when using Internet Explorer. None of my pc's show this and i'm not sure how to fix this.
Thanks

Comment: what version of IE are they using?

Comment: @Steve Robillard ~ I bet $20 it is IE6...

Comment: You lose $20 :-p they are using IE 8

Comment: @drachenstern you owe me 20 LOL
since the post is about a Canadian page that must be 20 Canadian.

Comment: Just tested in 32/64 bit IE on Win 7 no outlines.
Can you get him to send you a screen cap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the outline of the coordinates area, set your CSS there as folows:

```
p.style2,
p.style2:focus,
p.style2:active,
p.style2:hover {outline:none; border:0;}
```

Should take care of it, but if not you may try:

```
p.style2 map,
p.style2 map:focus,
p.style2 map:active,
p.style2 map:hover {outline:none; border:0;}
```

Hope it helps...

Btw: I've tested that link on FF, IE 7 & 8, Safari, Chrome and Opera Over Windows, and FF over Linux and it was all ok... my guess is that you're client has an old browser's version that needs to be updated

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers show a border around images inside `<a>` elements, though off my head it's a blue border rather than a black one. Try `border: none` instead of `outline: none`.

*EDIT* I can't reproduce it either.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you're using 24-bit .png background images with alpha transparency and your client must be using IE6 (which doesn't natively support this).  If this is the case then you need to implement a PNG transparency script.  Here are a few:

- http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/
- http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/
- http://jquery.khurshid.com/ifixpng.php

Comment: <del>The images don't have a transparent background</del> <ins>Ok, they do.</ins>. Also, these hacks can bring about other weird bugs, like links becoming unclickable, and cool stuff like that.

Comment: my client uses IE that comes with Win7

Comment: @user146780 ~ I just tested on that browser, I don't see that artifact. It must be a plugin issue.